# Rerencing a class from a Add-Type'd class gives error

Tags: c#, powershell, exception, add-type

I have one C# class (processcontroller.cs).

In this class I add other classes to a list object (these classes will be invoked later).

One of my sub classes looks like this:

```
namespace PowerShellTests
{
    public class Step1
    {
        public void Initialize()
        {
            try
            {
                File.Open("filethatdoesnotexist.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.LogException(exc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I define my process controller path and then set it's first sub class like so:

```
processController.steps[0] = $Step1Class
```

I define $Step1Class with the following 3 PS commands

```
$script = [io.file]::readalltext('step1.cs')
add-type $script -lang csharpversion3
$Step1Class = New-Object Step1
```

However on the last line of the above code I get an error:

> The name ExceptionHandler does not exist in the current context.

I understand why the error is firing, but other than having `ExceptionHandler` defined in the Step1 class itself what other options do I have? The reason I do not want to have it defined in Step1.cs is because that will mean I have to repeat it for every other step class.

Comment: what exactely is `ExceptionHandler`? A custom class? The class belong `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher` directive? this one haven't a method called `LogException(Exception e)`.

Comment: Sorry I should have said, the ExceptionHandler class is a custom class written by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that Powershell has no reference to your custom class (providing that it is a custom class).
Try compiling it and loading it in as a assembly.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("path to assembly")
```

Comment: Are you saying that I should create a class lib project and define ExceptionHandler in there? As of now I have just been creating the classes and referencing them from a folder.

Comment: I think that it is a way to deal with it. You need to load in a definition of ExceptionHandler one way or another so that Powershell knows about it. The benefit of having an assembly is that any other references your ExceptionHandler may have could be referenced in the assembly unless it is a reference outside that assembly which should also be referenced. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: If memory serves (please let me know if it is not so), I think you can create a class in Powershell scripting as well. Maybe you can define that class in Powershell if you don't really want to create an assembly. That way it should be defined throughout all your "steps".

Comment: I understand what you mean however after creating a class library and executing a line similar to your suggestion, how do I then create objects based on the classes in the DLL? I tried $PC = namespace.processcontroller and no errors were thrown but when I run Get-Member on $PC I get errors.

Comment: Here is a site that might assist with that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/03/11/how-to-create-an-object-in-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `add-type` for you custom class.
Then add the `using` directive for your custom class in all the others classes that need it
(this is the same way you do it in c#). Or use  `add-type` with

```
Add-type $script -UsingNamespace PowerShellTests.MycustomExceptionHandlerClass
```